# Different css stylesheet for routes

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, react-router-dom

I am quite new to react and react-router-dom. The problem is, I am trying to get different layouts for different routes in my application. But instead all of the css files for different routes just imported in one huge conflicting piece.

App looks like this:

```
<Router>
  < >
    <Navigation />
    <UpButton />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/research" component={Research} />
      <Route path="/publications" component={Publications} />
      <Route path="/student" component={Student} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Switch>
  </>
</Router>
```

Each component I am rendering looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import './home.scss';

// Utility
import Utility from 'components/utility/Utility';

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      < >
        <Utility />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Is there a way to import only the specific css file with specific route? Like home.css for '/' route, about.css for '/about' route specifically?

It might be the simple misunderstanding from me, but I really can't find any solution for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend to use the following file structure and pattern:

```
- components
  - Main.js
  - Utility
    - index.js
    - styles.scss
- pages
    - HomePage
      - index.js
      - styles.scss
```

Then specify the component related styles within the component's stylesheet, and the page-realated styles within the page's stylesheet. And use pages for routes, not components.
Finally, wrap every component into a specific class selector, and add wrap the belonging sass file into that selector (like `.home-page`).
For this reason, please, use **sass** instead of css, because you can embed style definitions within each other and use the top one as a "namespace". So the styles will not affect to each other.

```
// Main.js
  import HomePage from '../pages/HomePage';

  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/research" component={ResearchPage} />


// HomePage/index.js

  import Utility from './components/Utility';
  import './styles.scss';
  ...
  render(){
    <div className="home-page">
      <Utility />
    </div>
  }

// HomePage/styles.scss    
  .home-page {
    ...
  }

// Utility/index.js

  import './styles.scss';
  ...

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="utility-comp">
      ...
      </div>
  }


// Utility/styles.scss
  .utility-comp {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for reply!
I did the same and still, react imports all styling in one huge piece. I guess, when I do page imports, it takes imported styles with them alltogether.

Comment: I improved my answer with the advantages of using scss. Please, have a look.

Comment: Believe it or not, I was using .scss and did the same now. Rendering page component into div with className="page-name" and nesting layout inside of it

.page-name {
 @contents
}

It works now, perfect. Thank you!
Still, I have a feeling it can be done better way.

Thank you for help and your time.

Answer (score 3):

React made a SPA which mean: single page application.. all the resources are loaded on app startup, if other resource are loaded in a second moment this resources became available in the entire applications.

I think that to avoid conflict you need to work on better target your stile, for example you can wrap your page in a container with the pagename as class, for example:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div classname="home">
        <Utility />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Contact extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div classname="contact">
        /*...*/
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and then target your css using the page class:

```
.home h1{
color:red;
}

.contact h1{
color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I got the idea. I will try it now! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped me after about half an hour looking for which component imported specific CSS file which I didn't import in specific route, thanks !