# Different media queries for <html> for different routes in React

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, media-queries

Suppose two routes: `Guest` and `Dashboard`. Suppose that each of them is rendering within a div with the class name same as the name of the component.

Based on the ideas from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57323212/2725810) reply, I would like to have something like this:

```
// In guest.scss, imported from Guest.js
$bp: 75em; // 1200px
.Guest {
    html {
        font-size: 62.5%;

        @media only screen and (max-width: $bp) {
            font-size: 50%;
        }
    }
}

// In dashboard.scss, imported from Dashboard.js 
$bp: 50em; // 800px
.Dashboard {
    html {
        font-size: 62.5%;

        @media only screen and (max-width: $bp) {
            font-size: 45%;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, html is not inside these classes, so the above is wrong. So, how can I achieve different media queries for `<html>` for different routes?

Comment: But why do you need to set different queries on html level and not within specific components? You could have two containers Guest and Dashboard and set different css rules specifically for these containers

Comment: @JSEvgeny Because all my sizes are specified in rem and setting `font-size` in `<html>` scales everything.

Comment: Hmm good point! Weird, but after some research I was not able to find a proper solution. One possibility though is to use `em` (which refers to parent container size) instead

Comment: Wouldn't/shouldn't you use the `rem` unit for your font sizes so they are relative to the root element? Set the root size in `html` and then in the CSS for `Guest` and `Dashboard` override it in `rem` from that size.

Comment: @DrewReese What do you mean by "override it in `rem`"? Can you post a reply with an example?

Comment: @JSEvgeny I am quite new to web development and had an impression that changing the root font size in media queries for a number of breakpoints was the easiest (and hence most frequently used) way to adapt a design to a variety of screen sizes. Am I wrong? Because if I am right, then it seems that `rem` does not go well with designing for multiple screen sizes...

Comment: I meant that you set a base font size `html { font-size: 16px }` and then in component styling you set relative to this base size `.Guest { font-size: 1.5rem; // 16px * 1.5 -> 24px }`. If you change the base size to say, `20px`, then all font sizing works relative to this, so `.Guest` is then `20px * 1.5 -> 30px`.

Comment: @DrewReese But this does not give me a way to scale the whole `Guest` component using a single media query without scaling the whole `Dashboard` component by the same amount.

Comment: Do CSS rules and inheritance work differently in SASS? What does the style of the `Dashboard` have to do with the style of `Guest`? The `rem` unit is a scaling unit, perhaps you haven't explained well enough your use case or what you are wanting to scale from?

Comment: @DrewReese Because `Guest` and `Dashboard` are inside the same `<html>`. Hence, changing the root font size affects all the (S)CSS rules using `rem` in both components.